# how to write italic script in Rstudio

Tags: rna-seq, single-cell

I have got the problem on how to write the italic script in RStudio. I used the script in the screenshot and got the error "Error in grobs[[i]]: subscript out of bounds." [image]

Comment: Please replace the image with the actual text.

Comment: Have you ensured that all of the elements of `p` are grobs (things plottable by ggplot)? The error suggests that that's not that case, so try just iterating over `1:4` instead.

Comment: Seriously. It's even *easier* to paste the text!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because formatting text as italics is not a bioinformatics problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The title is misleading as this error doesn't have anything to do with making the font italic. In Seurat v2, FeaturePlot does not return a ggplot2 object by default, so `p` in your case is `NULL`. You need to set `do.return` to `TRUE` in the FeaturePlot call.

You should instead do:

```
library(Seurat)

p <- FeaturePlot(pbmc_small, head(pbmc_small@var.genes), do.return = TRUE)

for(i in 1:length(p)) {
  p[[i]] <- p[[i]] + theme(plot.title = element_text(face = 'italic'))
}

cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = p)
```

[image: featureplot]